# justifying contents of UIView on a character (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, format

I'd like to justify some strings in a UIView on one character like this:

```
  1 -   4
  5 -  11
 12 -  50
 51 - 225
```

or:

```
  1 - 4
  5 - 11
 12 - 50
 51 - 225
```

or:

```
  1-4
  5-11
 12-50
 51-225
```

Formatting each string with `%3d` and `myView.textAlignment = .center` gives me something like this:

```
  1-4
 5-11
 12-50
 51-225
```

Does Swift have other built-in justification options (like left-, center-, and right-justification), to do this?  If not, any ideas on how to do it easily?

Comment: You can use a fixed width font

Comment: I'm using Courier which is monospaced.

Comment: yes thats what I meant. You would need to edit your string and add the appropriate number of spaces

Comment: Center justification isn't enough. It doesn't know anything about `-` being some special character you want to line up. I have two ideas for how to do this: 1) make three labels: the two numbers, and one for just the dash in the middle, all laid out in a grid view. 2) Use spaces to line up the `-`s within a column of single labels

Comment: @Leo Dabus:  So, no simple/built in method?  I'll need to count the number of characters on each side of the string and pad it appropriately?

Comment: What is your original string? `let numbers = "1 - 4\n5 - 11\n12 - 50\n51 - 225"` ?

Comment: @Alexander - Reinstate Monica:  I like that, but with 6 UIViews, that will mean 18 labels.

Comment: @Leo Dabus:  each string will be created: ````lowerValue + "-" + upperValue + "\n"````

Comment: I guess I could still use ````%3d```` then right justify ````lowerValue```` and left justify ````upperValue````.

Comment: 18 labels, so what? That's a detailed table view with 9 cells. Speaking of which, have you thought of using a table view, which supports recycling these views?

Comment: I had not though of that...  There will be 6 columns that look similar, each with a range separated by a hyphen.

Comment: @Greg That's not a probelm

Answer (score 0):

Just create a helper to pad left or right your strings up to the desired length and pad your lower and upper values

---

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func paddingLeft(upTo length: Int = 3) -> Self {
        repeatElement(" ", count: Swift.max(0, length-count)) + self
    }
    func paddingRight(upTo length: Int = 3) -> Self {
        self + repeatElement(" ", count: Swift.max(0, length-count))
    }
}
```

---

If you would like to fix the resulting string you would need to breakup it into lines, then split the resulting lines and add the numbers.
Something like:

```
let numbers = "1-4\n5-11\n12-50\n51-225"
let lines = numbers.split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline)
let components = lines.map{$0.components(separatedBy:  "-")}
let padded = components.map{
    ($0.first?.paddingLeft() ?? "") + "-" + ($0.last?.paddingRight() ?? "")
}.joined(separator: "\n")
print(padded)  // "  1-4  \n  5-11 \n 12-50 \n 51-225\n"
```

---

This will print:

```
  1-4  
  5-11 
 12-50 
 51-225
```